# How to fill shape with Gradient in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

how can i pass LinearGradient to a shape (for example Rectangle) **just** in SwiftUI?

```
Rectangle().frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 200)
```

Comment: [`Rectangle.fill`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/rectangle/3286692-fill) and [`Rectangle.fill`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/rectangle/3286693-fill) (yes, they are slightly different, so you will need to look at them and decide which meets your needs)

Comment: @MadProgrammer Thank, right before you answer, i found that the fill method should be called as the first thing which is added and i was trying to use that as second parameter.

Comment: @MadProgrammer Both Rectangle.fill links are broken.

Comment: @drewster Good thing it's just a comment - you could search just  "SwiftUI rectangle"

Answer (score 29, accepted):

This should work:

```
static let gradientStart = Color(red: 239.0 / 255, green: 120.0 / 255, blue: 221.0 / 255)
static let gradientEnd = Color(red: 239.0 / 255, green: 172.0 / 255, blue: 120.0 / 255)

var body: some View {
  Rectangle()
    .fill(LinearGradient(
      gradient: .init(colors: [Self.gradientStart, Self.gradientEnd]),
      startPoint: .init(x: 0.5, y: 0),
      endPoint: .init(x: 0.5, y: 0.6)
    ))
    .frame(width: 300, height: 200)
}
```

Comment: could u explain what the x & y in ```startPoint``` and ```endPoint``` means? It just has a slightly different with 0 -> 0.6, what position it is rely on.

Answer (score 7):

### SwiftUI

Here is a possible solution.

```
struct TestSwiftUIView: View {
    let uiscreen = UIScreen.main.bounds

    var body: some View {
        Rectangle()
        .fill(
            LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [Color.clear, Color.black]),
                           startPoint: .top,
                           endPoint: .bottom))
        .frame(width: self.uiscreen.width,
               height: self.uiscreen.height,
               alignment: .center)
    }
}
```

This code snippet will produce a screen like that:

[image: Showing a screen with a gradient from white to black]

The `startPoint` and the `endPoint` are `UnitPoint`. For UnitPoints you have the following options:

```
.zero

.center

.leading

.trailing

.top

.bottom

.topLeading

.topTrailing

.bottomLeading

.bottomTrailing
```

Answer (score 2):

As of beta 6, you must set the forgroundColor to clear first.

```
Rectangle()
    .foregroundColor(.clear)
    .background(LinearGradient(gradient:  Gradient(colors: [Color("gradient1"), Color("gradient2")]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Rectangle().frame(width: UIScreen.main.bounds.width, height: 200) // You original code

.overlay(
    LinearGradient(gradient: Gradient(colors: [.red, .purple]), startPoint: .top, endPoint: .bottom))
)
```

Note that:

> When you apply an overlay to a view, the original view continues to provide the layout characteristics for the resulting view.